# Without using mod_rewrite, what is the best way to redirect all subdomains to https?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I am currently using mod_rewrite to redirect all subdomains to https, but multiple sources have suggested that

> Using mod_rewrite to do this isn't the recommended behavior. See
>   [RedirectSSL](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS)

The [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/avoid.html) suggest Redirect and RedirectMatch:

> A common use for RewriteRule is to redirect an entire class of URLs.
>   For example, all URLs in the /one directory must be redirected to
>   http://one.example.com/, or perhaps all http requests must be
>   redirected to https.
>
> These situations are better handled by the Redirect directive.
>   Remember that Redirect preserves path information. That is to say, a
>   redirect for a URL /one will also redirect all URLs under that, such
>   as /one/two.html and /one/three/four.html.

Unfortunately, both of these documents (and anything else I have found) are only considering matching a single domain, rather than all subdomains. RedirectMatch seems like a good candidate for a relatively simple task like this, but I can't seem to get "http" to match as I expect:

```
RedirectMatch permanent "^http://(.*)$" "https://$1"
```

My guess as to why that doesn't work is because the redirectMatch is looking for a path and not a URI, but at this point I am stuck. Is it possible to accomplish a redirect of all subdomains to https without mod_rewrite, or is that the best available method?

Comment: Are you kidding me with this duplicate flag? The first three words of the title are *without using mod_rewrite*. I literally could not have been more specific about how the mod_rewrite canonical answer is not applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, for sub domains of different VHosts, I append the following line to each.

```
Redirect permanent / https://bar.example.com/
```

I normally just add one of these for each subdomain. If you have a very large number of sub domains, this method may not be very scalable, but it's simple and gets the job done.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct, as given the extent to which people have ignored the specifics of this question it would seem that there is not a (sans-mod_rewrite) alternative to just listing every subdomain as you suggest. Thank you for actually reading!